# Which statistical test is suitable to derive the probability of significance in difference (p-value)

Tags: statistical-significance

Help me in finding the suitable statistical test to show the significance difference [through p-value]

```
> Sample_data
  Universe subset
x     2200      5
y     2500     50
```

From the above data, I want to find whether the proportion of "Universe" that are in "subset" for x and y are significantly different.

Like, x and y subsets are 0.2% [5/2200*100] and 2% [50/2500*100], hence there is 10 fold difference between x and Y. But, how could I achieve this through a statistical test, and which test is most appropriate in R environment?

How I can carry the universe proportions to determine the significant difference between subset of x(5) and y(50)?

---

The data structure refers a matrix. X has a total number of genes - 2200 (X-Universe) and Y has a total number of genes - 2500 (Y-Universe). Out of all X-2200, only 5 correspond to subset (a category-P) and out of Y-2500, 50 correspond to the same subset (or category-P). And I want to say the x and y subset values (5 and 50) are significantly different with respect to the total number of genes in X and Y (2200 and 2500). Statistically **how can we determine that the 5 out of 2200 and 50 out of 2500 are significantly different?**

Comment: It looks like one answer to your question might be Fisher's exact test.  But I'm having trouble understanding your question. You use unusual phrases like "universe values" and I'm not sure what that means.  What do your data look like?

Comment: Like @JeremyMiles I don't understand your question. The stuff in the box is not "data" even though you call it that. Since you are using R you should post data in a format that would be comprensible by R ... some sort of matrix or data frame, probably.

Comment: dput is great in situations like this, because it would let us see exactly what you have datawise.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to compare two proportions using Fisher's exact test. Here are the results as computed by an [online free calculator](http://www.graphpad.com/quickcalcs/contingency1/):

```
        Outcome1  Outcome2  Total
Group 1 5   2195    2200
Group 2 50  2450    2500
Total   55  4645    4700
```

Fisher's exact test
  The two-tailed P value is less than 0.0001
  The association between rows (groups) and columns (outcomes) 
   is considered to be extremely statistically significant.

That answers your question. It might be useful to quantify the ratio of the two proportions with a confidence interval as that is often more informative than just a P value. The relative risk is  0.11 with a 95% confidence interval ranging from
0.045 to 0.28. Looked at the other way (reciprocal), the relative risk is 8.80 with the 95% CI ranging from 3.51 to 22.03. One set of genes has almost 9 times the "hits" of the other, and you can be 95% sure (given some assumptions) that the range of 3.5 to 22 includes the true ratio.

You have strong evidence that the difference in "hit rate" (whatever the experimental details are) between the two sets of genes would be very unlikely to occur by chance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a chi-square test (`?chisq.test`) or Fisher's exact test (`?fisher.test`), or a two sample proportions test (`?prop.test`). Each will accept a matrix as input, but instead of total count and count in subset, you need count in subset and count not in subset. For example:

```
Sample.data <- matrix(c(5,2200,50,2500),byrow=TRUE,nr=2)
rownames(Sample.data) <- c("x","y")
colnames(Sample.data) <- c("subset","Universe")

with(as.data.frame(Sample.data),prop.test(subset,Universe))

Sampletable <- cbind(Sample.data[,1],(Sample.data[,2]-Sample.data[,1]))    
chisq.test(Sampletable)
fisher.test(Sampletable)
prop.test(Sampletable) # Same result as first prop.test and chisquare.test
```

All three give very similar results on large samples. You might notice the p-value on `prop.test` and `chisq.test` is the same; when you do a two-tailed two-sample proportions test it actually does the same test by default.

Comment: Dear Glen_b and Harvey, Your comments on my query is exactly what I looking for. And I'm absolutely happy with your response.I'm sorry to make You feel like. Thanking You.

Comment: This is what I was referring to: http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers